# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition GUI issue

Tags: user-interface, graphics, visual-studio-2015

Everytime I open a more complex project in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, the GUI gets messed up. As you can see in the picture, menu titles are downscaling and some are unclickable. The same applies to text. Everything related to the GUI just breaks.

As a solution I tried disabling "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" and "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" but none seem to work.

Can it be related to the fact that i am using a 2K screen with custom DPI settings? Has anyone else experienced the same problem? If so, how did you get rid of it?

LE: Sometimes Visual Studio also crashes after the UI gets messed up.

[image: UI Failure]

Comment: Why don't you try VS with standard DPI-Settings and see if the problem goes away? This test should only take a couple of minutes. Is your 2K screen completely unusable with the standard settings? I have used VS2015 (Pro and Enterprise) on several Machines with standard screens (and standard DPI-Settings) and never noticed this problem... BTW: the project in your screenshot can hardly be called a complex project.

Comment: I tried all the possible settings including the standard dpi settings, windows xp scaling on and off etc. The same thing happened no matter what. I even called Microsoft support and they couldn't give me a solution. I have come to the point where I am backing up my computer in order to install Windows 10 and see if the issue gets solved. As for the last statement you made, I took the screenshot with something worthless in order to protect my code.

Comment: @cookiemonster - turning on the "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" doesn't resolve this for you? There is a known graphics card issue with Visual Studio that we're digging into. If you run dxdiag, save all the information and crack it open, can you let me know the details of your graphics card? Thanks!
Cathy
Visual Studio IDE Team